# Не заполняется таблица БД через mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Пытаюсь заполнить таблицу через mysql.connector,таблица создается,но не заполняется,что не так?При этом ошибок никаких не выдает.

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database="db",user='root',password='25063518')

    if conn.is_connected():
        print('Connected to MySQL database')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE tb2(id INT(255),message VARCHAR(1000),classificator VARCHAR(50))")
    for elem in arr:
        sql = ("INSERT INTO tb2 (message) VALUES ('{}')").format(elem)
        cursor.execute(sql)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не компетентен в питоне. Но, транзакции автокомитятся или нужно ручками?

Comment: а я и не знаю))

Comment: Попробуйте вызвать `conn.commit()` после цикла

Comment: Спасибо,помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ товарища [JVic](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/193183/jvic) из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1139457/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%91%d0%94-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-mysql-connector#comment1971008_1139457) к вопросу:

> Попробуйте вызвать `conn.commit()` после цикла